# can you tell concept behind working of this?

Tags: java

**not able to clearly know the concepts behind**

```
public class MyClass
{
  private int a;
  public double b;

  public MyClass(int first, double second)
  {
    this.a = first;
    this.b = second;
  }

  // new method
  public static void incrementBoth(MyClass c1) {
    c1.a = c1.a + 1;
    c1.b = c1.b + 1.0;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    MyClass c1 = new MyClass(10, 20.5);
    MyClass c2 = new MyClass(10, 31.5);
    // different code below
    incrementBoth(c2);
    System.out.println(c1.a + ", "+ c2.a);
  }
}
```

output is 10,11 not able to get incrementboth(c2)
and debug is not helping

```
public class MyClass
{
    private int a;
    public double b;

    public MyClass(int first, double second)
    {
        this.a = first;
        this.b = second;
    }

    public static void incrementBoth(MyClass c1) {
        c1.a = c1.a + 1;
        c1.b = c1.b + 1.0;
    }

    // new method
    public static void incrementA(int first)
    {
        first = first + 1;
    }

    // new method
    public static void incrementB(double second)
    {
        second = second + 1.0;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        MyClass c1 = new MyClass(10, 20.5);
        MyClass c2 = new MyClass(10, 31.5);
        // different code below
        incrementA(c2.a);
        incrementB(c2.b);

        System.out.println(c2.a + ", "+ c2.b);
    }
}
```

here the output is 10,31.5 but why is c2.a and c2.b not incrmenented??
as c2.a is passed here but it doesent increase

(fsvfvvfvvvfdvfdvfvvfvfvfvfv)

Comment: What's the problem with it?

Comment: Which part do you not understand? `c2` is passed to `incrementBoth`. The value `10` is incremented. Then you display `c1.a` and `c2.a` (which return 10 and 11 respectively).

Comment: Java always passes by value. For non-object types (int, float, etc.), this means the value as we would think of it. So incrementA and incrementB merely add one to their argument, but it is not returned. For object types (like c1 and c2), the value of the object is their reference, so incrementBoth(c1) points to the c1 instance and can modified the instance variables.

Comment: i understood,       c2.a=10,when passed value of first will be increased

Answer (score 3):

Write it down on paper, and follow the code.

```
MyClass c1 = new MyClass(10, 20.5);
MyClass c2 = new MyClass(10, 31.5);

c1 = X
c2 = Y

      X             Y
┌──────────┐  ┌──────────┐
│ a = 10   │  │ a = 10   │
│ b = 20.5 │  │ b = 20.5 │
└──────────┘  └──────────┘

incrementBoth(c2);

      X             Y
┌──────────┐  ┌──────────┐
│ a = 10   │  │ a = 11   │
│ b = 20.5 │  │ b = 21.5 │
└──────────┘  └──────────┘
```

Remember, the parameter name `c1` inside `incrementBoth()` has nothing whatsoever so do with the local variable named `c1` inside `main()`. When you call `incrementBoth(c2)`, the `c1` *parameter* refers to the `Y` object reference by the `c2` *local variable*, so it is the `Y` object that gets incremented.

Answer (score 2):

The name of the parameter of a method has no relation to the name of an actual parameter you pass to the method. You could name the parameter `foo` for example:

```
  public static void incrementBoth(MyClass foo) {
    foo.a = foo.a + 1;
    foo.b = foo.b + 1.0;
  }
```

It just increments the fields of an object which was passed to it, not fields of a local variable `c1`. Since you pass `c2` - it increments fields of `c2`.

Answer (score 2):

You have passed object, `c2` (i.e. `MyClass c2 = new MyClass(10, 31.5)`) in the following statement

```
incrementBoth(c2);
```

which increases the members of the object, `c2` (i.e. `MyClass c2 = new MyClass(10, 31.5)`). Since you haven't passed object, `c1` (i.e. `MyClass c1 = new MyClass(10, 20.5)`) in the above method call, its members remain as they are.

Therefore, in the following statement, `c1.a` gets printed as `10`  (i.e. original value) while `c2.a` gets printed as `11` (i.e. increased value).

```
System.out.println(c1.a + ", "+ c2.a);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   public static void incrementA(int first)
    {
        first = first + 1;
    }
```

This code has no effect. It increments the local variable "first", which is a COPY of the variable passed to the call to incrementA(), and then that variable goes out of scope when the method returns.
Since "a" is an instance variable, your incrementA() method should look like:

```
public void incrementA() {
   ++a;
}
```

and you call it from main using

```
c1.incrementA();
```

You could also have the method return the new value by writing it as

```
public int incrementA() {
   return  ++a;
}
```

and calling it:

```
int newValue = c1.incrementA();
```